# Moving emails in Thunderbird lost them on my server

Tags: email, sync, imap

A couple of years ago I migrated servers to a different provider and the settings changed so that sent emails got copied to different IMAP folders when sending from different devices. Recently I tried to fix this, and changed the settings for send copies, but then I tried to correct the last 2 years history of dispersed, sent emails.  I highlighted all emails in Sent Items and Sent Messages and dragged them the the Sent folder (my preferred repository). On Thunderbird they all appear to be there, but on my phone and on my server I've now lost my last 2 years history of sent emails. They're not in any folder on my server, and I need to retain them.

As an experiment, I right-clicked one missing email located on Thunderbird and selected *Move to "Sent" Again*, hoping that this would sync the email to my server, but it just disappeared from Sent and now appears to be lost.  So I won't be trying that again!

How can I copy the emails I now only seem to hold locally on Thunderbird back to my IMAP server so they're secure and accessible on all my devices?  And is there any security action I can take to prevent further loss while I try to restore these emails?

Comment: 1. If you right-click on a sent message, and select *Copy To > <Account Name> > Sent*, giving time for another device to check that box, does that work? 2. Try copying the items showing in Sent to a *local* folder, delete them from Sent, and then *copy them back to Sent*. * If neither work, there may a rule on the IMAP provider *preventing* it; contact the service provider for help. BTW, move only a few files at a time - experiment, because some servers place a traffic limit.

Comment: Also, make sure you are subscribed to the folder, so you can actually see it.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion @DrMoishePippik. I tried (1) without success. Trying (2) I did get it to copy to another folder, and that copy appeared on my IMAP server. But deleting the Sent copy and copying that back to Sent puts it into the copy on Thunderbird but not my IMAP server. I don’t think it’s a space issue because newly sent emails are copied to Sent okay. Doesn’t make sense to me!

Comment: @Billysugger, If  you can transfer all the (local) Sent to to a new folder on the IMAP server, is there another interface for that server, e.g., browser-based, that would allow you move them from that new folder to (server) Sent? If not, could the server provider do that for you?